# Res Assured AssertionError handling

Tags: java, error-handling, rest-assured

I have an API test that asserts values. Currently it reads rows from excel then it loops in a normal for loop. This is working very well if the values do match.

However if an assertion fails the test ends with a stacktrace AssertionError
Is there a way to continue with the test even if one assertion fails ?

The basic structure looks like:

```
<code>
  try {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            //Get Excel Data
                String progress = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString();
            //Excel Assert Values
                String valueToAssert = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(29).toString();

            baseURI = "url";

                Response response =
                        given()
                                //.filter(new AllureRestAssured())
                                .body(String.valueOf(writer))
                                .when()
                                .post()
                                .then()
                                .assertThat()
                                .statusCode(200)
                                .and()
                                .body("value", equalTo(valueToAssert))
 }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (AssertionError k){
            k.printStackTrace();
        }
    }





</code>
```

Comment: Can i first ask why? :-) You are doing multiple assertions for a reason. If one assert fails, the test should fail. 

Also, you don't have to catch the exceptions, just add them to your test method "throws". This makes your tests cleaner and Junit will print the stacktrace for you

Comment: Sorry a bit new to this. Basically each row in the excel is 1 test case. For example we have 10 rows in the excel we have 10 API tests and 10 different values that needs to be asserted. I am open to any suggestions to get this working.Thank you for the "throws" suggestion

Comment: No problem. :-) We all started somewhere.

So you actually want multiple tests. Try to NEVER use a for loop, as that will lead to the issue you are having.

Instead of that, use parameterized tests. 
For Junit 5:  https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5
For Junit 4: https://mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/

This will actually create multiple tests which can fail individually.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to never use a for loop in your tests**, as that will lead to the issue you are having.

Instead of that, use parameterized tests.

- For Junit 5: baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5
- For Junit 4: mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test

Using Parameterized Tests will create multiple tests which can fail individually.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I actually got this to work. I had to move my catch one level up if that makes sense. Its working very well now and i can do custom error messages with the catch as well. In the above example how would you parameterize input from excel. If you have a good tutorial you can share that would be great. So would be the same concept